# Filter data.table by quantity of group

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a `data.table` like

```
sample<-data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
                   name=c("apple","apple","orange","orange",
                          "pear","pear","pear","banana","banana"),
               atr=c("pretty","ugly","bruised","delicious",
                     "pear-shaped","bruised","infested",
                     "too-ripe","perfect"),
               N=c(10,9,15,4,5,7,7,4,12))
```

I want to return essentially `unique(sample[,list(id, name)])` except that I also want the `atr` column for the value with the greatest N.  In cases where there is a tie for highest N then I don't care which of the two is picked but I want only one to be picked.

This almost works `merge(sample[,list(N=max(N)),by=list(id,name1)], sample,by=c("id","name1","N"))` but since pear has two `atr` values that tie for max this returns two pears.  Besides it not giving the intended result, I also assume/hope there's a way to do this that doesn't involve the join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `order`:

```
> unique(sample[order(-N), .(id, name, atr)], by = c("id", "name"))
   id   name     atr
1:  2 orange bruised
2:  4 banana perfect
3:  1  apple  pretty
4:  3   pear bruised
```

If you want to maintain overall sorting, just use `order(id, name, -N)` instead.

You could also split this to two lines:

```
setorder(sample, -N) #done by reference, as with all set* functions in data.table
unique(sample[ , .(id, name, atr)], by = c("id", "name"))
```

Or perhaps better depending on your end goal:

```
setkey(setorder(sample, -N), id, name)
unique(sample[ , .(id, name, atr)])
```

(note: order is crucial in this last, as using `setorder` first will overwrite keys to `NULL`)

Comment: I didn't know unique accepted a `by`.  I was also surprised that this was faster than the approach by Richard.  Granted it was the difference between .001 and .005 seconds (for my actual dataset) so it doesn't have any real world impact.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor yes, the `by` argument is especially useful if a) you want to keep your original `data.table`'s key intact while using `unique` and b) if you want to go `unique` on some but not all of the keys of your `data.table`.

Comment: Makes me wish for a by argument in head and tail

Comment: @ClaytonStanley `head(dt[,.SD[1],by=keys])`

Comment: I was thinking head(dt, 1, by=keys)

Comment: @ClaytonStanley That is what that code will do; of course you're encouraged to [submit a feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) if you'd like that built into the `head`/`tail` functions

Answer (score 4):

You could use `atr[N == max(N)][1]` to return only the first in the case of a tie, like this -

```
library(data.table)

sample[, .(atr = atr[N == max(N)][1]), by = .(id, name)]
#    id   name     atr
# 1:  1  apple  pretty
# 2:  2 orange bruised
# 3:  3   pear bruised
# 4:  4 banana perfect
```

**Note:** As Frank points out `atr[N == max(N)][1]` is also simply `atr[which.max(N)]`

Comment: This is just for reference since I had to do something like this recently, but if you want to handle cases with a tie in a more complicated way, you may want to do something like `sample[,{x<-atr[N==max(N)]; if(length(x)>1) x else *case of tie action*},by=.(id,name)]`

Comment: You can get the first match with `which.max`, right? `atr = atr[which.max(N)]`

Comment: @Frank - Yes, exactly right. That's the function I couldn't recall last night!  Cheers